# How to group a lists of commands into a single keyword?

Tags: csh

I am currently using the csh shell.
Everytime I would like to compile my codes, I have to do a lot of cd stuffs.

For example{

```
cd ~/path1/path2/path3
make depend
make 
make install
```

}

I am wondering if it is possible I can add something into (ex: **.cshrc file**) 
so I can define a new keyword, which replace all the commands i have to type before to save some time.

Comment: You mean, like an [`alias`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/378440/13377)? What exactly would you want to type that would expand into the list of commands you've noted above? More details please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for  [`alias`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/378440/13377).

If you just want to run the commands in your question as a new command, and you don't want to put them in a script, you could make an alias in your `.cshrc` script like this:

```
alias foo 'cd ~/path1/path2/path3 && make depend && make && make install'
```

Now, running `foo` in your shell will run all those commands. and will stop running the list of commands if any one of the commands fails. (That's what `&&` is for.)

You can use notation that looks like history substitution to retrieve options in aliases. For example:

```
alias foo 'cd ~/path1/path2/\!:1 && make depend && make && make install'
```

This will allow you to run something like `foo bar` and the alias will `cd ~/path1/path2/bar`.  Note that this is just doing substitution; in this case, if you were to leave out the option and just run `foo`, your chain of `make`s would be run in `~/path1/path2/`. If this is a concern ... write a shell script instead of using an alias.